# CONDIÇÃO IP do usuário via Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, redes, ip

Blz galera, estou com uma grande dificuldade com JAVASCRIPT, estou tendo problema com meu PHP para retornar o IP com função

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

mas esta, me retorna apenas o gateway da nossa rede, acreditamos que seja algum problema interno. Daí recorri ao javascript abaixo, que está me retornando o ip publico e para mim, já ajuda bastante.

O que eu gostaria é o seguinte, a partir desse ip que está sendo mostrado pelo javascript, fazer um alert redirecionando se os 10 primeiros algarismos forem diferentes de 200.254.21 sair da pagina.

Não sei trabalhar com if no javascript. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?",
          function(json) {
            document.write("Meu IP público é: ", json.ip);
          }
        );
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: O que exatamente você está tentando fazer?

Comment: @web_charles se for uma validação crítica que não possa ser burlada, deve ser feita via PHP. E não é uma "falha interna", o servidor vai pegar o gateway do seu roteador mesmo, a não ser que você use IPv6 ou tenha IPv4 válido em cada equipamento. Agora se quiser validar um equipamento interno de uma rede via servidor, via IP não dá, o correto seria um login e senha, uma token, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer autenticar a conexão pelo IP?

Esse tipo bloqueio chama-se ACL ou Listas de Controle de Acesso e só serve para barrar a grande parte dos usuários leigos.

As Listas de Controle de Acesso(ACL) permitem permitir ou negar tráfego de endereços IP específicos para um endereço IP e uma porta de destino específicos. Também permite especificar tipos diferentes de tráfego, como ICMP, TCP, UDP, etc.

**Devem ser implementada no roteador** e não no código, nem cliente e nem servidor.

Não deve ser o único critério de autenticação, esse tipo de proteção só funciona como aparato de barragem para a grande massa de usuários leigos. Não funciona com invasores especializados pois é 100% suscetível a um Host Header Attack, que consiste em plantar informações falsas em requisições, no caso o atacante gera uma série de requisições falsas  cada uma com um IP diferente formado assim uma tabela com os ips aceitos e rejeitados pela ACL .

É tipo de validação utilizado para bloquear o "tiozão" chato que quer roubar Wifi na festa mas que não impede o filho do seu vizinho, de 10 anos, de roubar sua conexão internet.

As duas respostas mais o código da pergunta não podem oferecem certeza alguma sobre a veracidade dos IP entregue pois podem ser burlados com uma linha de código utilizando a ferramenta do desenvolvedor do próprio browser.

Se você quer autenticar a comunicação sugiro dois modelos, *Autenticação Baseada em Sessão* e a *Autenticação Baseada em Token*.

**Autenticação Baseada em Sessão**

Na Autenticação Baseada em Sessão, o servidor criará uma sessão para o usuário após o login.

O ID da sessão é armazenado em um cookie no navegador do usuário. Enquanto o usuário permanecer conectado, o cookie será enviado juntamente com todas as solicitações subsequentes.

O servidor pode então comparar o ID da sessão armazenada no cookie com as informações da sessão armazenadas na memória para verificar a identidade do usuário e enviar resposta com o estado correspondente.

**Autenticação Baseada em Token**

Muitos aplicativos da Web usam JSON Web Token (JWT) em vez de sessões para autenticação. No aplicativo baseado em token, o servidor cria o JWT com um segredo e envia o JWT para o cliente. O cliente armazena o JWT (geralmente no armazenamento local) e inclui o JWT no cabeçalho a cada solicitação. O servidor validaria o JWT com todas as solicitações do cliente e envia uma resposta.

A maior diferença é que o estado do usuário não é armazenado no servidor, pois o estado é armazenado dentro do token no lado do cliente. A maioria dos aplicativos Web modernos usa o JWT para autenticação por razões que incluem escalabilidade e autenticação de dispositivo móvel.

Answer (score -2):

Em primeiro lugar, você deve remover esta linha: `<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>`, pois a utilização desta API já está sendo feita aqui:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?",
    function(json) { ... }
```

Não é uma boa idéia fazer isso via javascript. O ideal é que esse tipo de verificação ocorra no servidor. De qualquer forma, segue o código.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?",
    function(json) {
      document.write("Meu IP público é: ", json.ip);
      if(!json.ip.startsWith("200.254.21")) {
        alert('IP DIFERENTE');
        console.log('IP DIFERENTE');
        // redirecionamento
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
      } else {
          alert('IP IGUAL');
          console.log('IP IGUAL');
      }
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Entendi. O alert não aparece, não funciona será que isso mesmo !json.ip.startsWith ?

Comment: Se você quer que redirecione quando o IP começar com 200.254.22, é só trocar `!json.ip.startsWith("200.254.21")` por `json.ip.startsWith("200.254.21")`

Comment: Certo. Infelizmente o alert não aparece mesmo quando mudo

Comment: Se o alert não aparece em nenhum dos dois casos, você está com outro tipo de problema. Rode a nova resposta e veja o que aparece no seu console.